# Reuse Parameter names in PetaPoco

Tags: c#, sql-server, petapoco

When the following C# PetaPoco code is execute:

```cs
var p = db.Fetch<Person>("WHERE (firstname=@0 or lastname=@0)", "John");
```

Or even

```cs
var p = db.Fetch<Person>("WHERE (firstname=@name or lastname=@name)"
       , new { name = "John" });
```

The resulting SQL is:

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'
Select * from Person 
WHERE (firstname=@0 or lastname=@1)'
   ,N'@0 nvarchar(4000)
   ,  @1 nvarchar(4000)'
   ,  @0=N'John'
   ,  @1=N'John'
```

Of course this is a simplified example, but why is it producing multiple sql parameters (@0 and @1), when it could reuse the same one (@0)?

And is there any way to force PetaPoco to reuse named parameters?

Comment: PetaPoco only creates the ADO.net params and execute the command. Where did you get the resulting SQL?

Comment: From SQL Server Profiler, it's the SQL that was generated by PetaPoco.

Comment: I think it's generated by ADO.net

Comment: NPoco will reuse parameters if they have the same value.

Comment: @Schotime Are there breaking changes if I swap PetaPoco for NPoco?

Comment: @BradBamford if there is there wouldn't be many. Especially not for CRUD.

Comment: This obvious oversight bugs me to no end. There seems to be no point in even numbering the variables within the SQL. The algorithm merely inserts parameters in the order in which they appear. Numbering them gives the false impression that the library supports any kind of meaningful indexing.